# Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.1.2, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0

Tags: cordova, plugins, geolocation

When i build my app on PhoneGap, i have this message on Logs :

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" at "4.0.1" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.1.2, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-geolocation' for android
```

I used the command :

```
cordova platforms add android@6.3.0
```

For "**cordova platform version android**" :

```
Installed platforms:
android 6.3.0
ios 4.1.1
```

My "config.xml" :

```
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~4.0.1" />
<engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
```

My App is build with Ionic/Cordova, and i dont know why PhoneGap say this message.

I have try to remove my project on PhoneGap and create new app but it's not working.

Someone can help me ?

Ty :)

Comment: reinstall the plugin after updating android version may be?

Comment: I have try but not working :/

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap was the problem :)

Use Ionic "testing you app"

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html